# Tableless model in rails with form_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been having trouble with tableless models in rails 3.x. I've looked at a bunch of questions here on stack overflow and while I've tried to implement them I haven't figured it out yet. I want the form not to submit unless the two text field tags have been filled. It doesn't have to check if its valid data but I just want a basic check on the form itself.

I have my form code here:

```
<%= form_tag '/page' do %>
    <%= label_tag %>
    <%= text_field_tag %>
    <%= label_tag %>
    <%= text_field_tag %>
    <br />
    <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

which then passes it off to a controller:

```
def page
    @page = Hourly.new(params)
    @page.function_call
end
```

which then goes to the model:

```
class Hourly

    include ActiveModel::Validations
    attr_reader params
    attr_accessor params
    validates_presence_of params
    def initialize(params)
    end
end
```

Is there something I am not adding to check the validation of the text_field_tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you submitting the form data to if it's a tableless model?  What I would do is use jQuery to disable the form button unless both of those fields have a value.  Or, better yet...use client_side_validations gem and set up a required validation for those two fields...it will not allow the form to even be submitted if the validation fails.

Comment: I'm trying to actually insert the data into a api call and then parse that get request and display it on another page. I will look at the client side validations gem.

Comment: Nvm I figured out that error but now I am getting this: couldn't find file 'rails.validations'
  (in app/assets/javascripts/application.js:15)

Comment: Figured out my error. Just had to restart the server. The gem is not doing the proper validation on the fields but I was pointed in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: New update, client_side_validations will never work with form_tag

Comment: Use simpeform gem with client side validations.  It too will make your life much easier.